# MYSQL has orderBy on count(*) some impact on perfomance?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, database-performance

I have a simple query which count the number of records is a plain Query with some inner Joins and some criterions.

something like this.

```
select count(*)
from ......
where ....
order by .........at most 4 fields.
```

My question the order by **asc** or **desc** at most 4 fields has some impact on the performance? or is just ignore or optimized by the engine.

Sorry if the question is plain or simple best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I should note that your query, as written, will return exactly one row.  You have an aggregation function with no `GROUP BY`.  In this situation, the `ORDER BY` is basically a no-op (I don't know if MySQL goes through the motions for one row or not).

In general, the performance impact of `order by` depends on the number of *rows*, not the number of *keys*.

I can only think of two occasions when an `order by` has minimal impact on performance:

- An index can be used for the ordering.
- It follows a `GROUP BY` and uses the aggregation keys (this is only true in MySQL which does a sort for the `GROUP BY`).

And, of course, an `ORDER BY` on few rows (such as 4 *rows*) would be pretty negligible performance-wise.

The impact, though, has much less to do with the size of the keys than with the number of rows and the overall size of the rows.  With multiple joins and a `WHERE` clause, it is unlikely (but not impossible) that your query could use an index for the `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 1):

In mysql DOC http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

> In some cases, MySQL can use an index to satisfy an ORDER BY clause
>   without doing extra sorting.
>
> The index can also be used even if the ORDER BY does not match the
>   index exactly, as long as all unused portions of the index and all
>   extra ORDER BY columns are constants in the WHERE clause

In you case using count the index don't should be used (bacause is not part fo an index ) and then in some way thsi kind of order by has an impact on performance.

Respect to you question is not ignored  and is not optimized   by engine